# web.config Membership Type Error

Tags: asp.net, web-config, asp.net-membership

I'm attempting to make the login requirements for Password less strict.  I set all of my attributes in the web.config file, but for some reason, it doesn't like my Type attribute.  I've looked at all of the other posts concerning web.config Membership on StackOverflow, as well as other sites, and they all seem to have the exact line that I do for Type.  I can't seem to find much about this error in my searches, either.  I just can't figure out why I am getting this error:

```
Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Attribute not recognized 'writeExceptionsToEventLog'

  Source Error:  
  Line 16:         <clear />
  Line 17:         <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"  
  Line 18:              type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"  
  Line 19:              connectionStringName="CafeWorksConnectionString"
  Line 20:              requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
```

Here is my web.config file (slightly modified to remove sensitive info)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="validationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms" />
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
             connectionStringName="CafeWorksConnectionString"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="4" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
             passwordAttemptWindow="10" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="8"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="Name@EmailHost.com">
        <network host="EmailHost" password="" userName="" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <connectionStrings>
        <add name="CafeWorksConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DB;Initial Catalog=DBCatalog;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

If anyone knows how to correct this error I'd appreciate the help.  I have absolutely no idea where "writeExceptionsToEventLog" is taking place and why it is causing my error.

Thank you!

Comment: I found in the code where I was trying to write to the Exceptions log (which was no where near the line showing error).  Once I fixed that, I got a more serious error, so I think the users will just have to get used to long, annoying passwords. :)

Comment: There is no `writeExceptionsToEventLog` attribute in membership provider. Could you remove `writeExceptionsToEventLog="false"` and try again?

Comment: Hi Win.  I noticed that.  I removed that code from the web.config file and I received an error telling me that it could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.  That can't be good.  I'm trying to research the reason, but if anyone could summarize what that means, I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your last comment, you are using legacy Membership Provider. It uses store procedures and dated.

Please use [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx) which uses Entity Framework.

### How to replace with New Membership Provider

**I assume you are implementing a new project. The reason is new Universal Provider creates table without prefix aspnet_ which is good. However, it'll break the relationship with custom tables if you are working on an existing project.**

Follow the Scott Hanselman's article and work on a new test project first.

Basically, you just need to replace `name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider"`.

Since you replace the name, you also need to up the defaultProvider to - `defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider"`

The rest are the same. New Universal Provider uses ***Entity Framework Code First***, so it'll create required tables for you automatically if they haven't been created yet. *Note, it doesn't use store procedure.*

The beauty is that you do not need to run aspnet_regsql.exe to create schema and store procedures.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, I can't just change the password requirements and I need to install a custom membership "database"?  The link you provided looks very detailed.  Is this a straight forward process?  Is there installation involved?  My boss gets twitchy about that.  Keep in mind, I'm a noob. :)

Comment: If I just need to add this code to my web.config file, where are the changes applied?  I've tried to publish my webpage (without making any membership changes) and the login is giving me an error.  It's telling me it can't find the server - I never defined a server for the login VB did that on its own.  Will I have the same issue here?  I'm sorry, I don't understand "Membership" very well.  It's my first attempt.

Comment: ***You need to define a connection string in web.config in order for any membership provider to work with SQL server.*** ASP.Net Membership is a little bit hard to understand at first, but you can learn it by reading the article and follow the instruction step-by-step. *If it still throws an exception, please search in StackOverflow first; I'm sure someone has already encountered the same problem before.*

Comment: OK Win, thank you.  I've tried a bunch of suggestions that I found searching stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me.  rather than continue with just comments, I've taken all of my code changing attempts and stack traces and asked a more specific question with hopefully all of the necessary code and stack traces.  I will try to work through the article that you provided for me.  It's a bit over my head, but I'll try.  Thank you for all of your help and patience.